# counting in pandas dataframe, for each a_i, a_j of A, count number of times that a_i and a_j are listed with a same b

Tags: pandas, numpy, count, binary-matrix

I have a big dataframe (1M lines) with two columns A,B.

For each couple a_i, a_j of A, I want to know the number of b in B such that there is both rows a_i,b and a_j,b

For example :

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 |
| a2 | b1 |
| a3 | b2 |
| a1 | b3 |
| a3 | b3 |
| a4 | b3 |
| a2 | b4 |
| a1 | b5 |
| a3 | b5 |
| a3 | b6 |
| a4 | b6 |

here I have, among others, the couple a1,a3 that share b3 and b5

The result would be the following matrix (that, by definition, is symetric) :

|  | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | xx | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| a2 | 1 | xx | 0 | 0 |
| a3 | 2 | 0 | xx | 2 |
| a4 | 1 | 0 | 2 | xx |

I think that the following would work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['a1','a2','a3','a1','a3','a4','a2','a1','a3','a3','a4'],
 'B':['b1','b1','b2','b3','b3','b3','b4','b5','b5','b6','b6']})

df_dum = df.set_index('A')['B'].str.get_dummies().reset_index()
df_dum = df_dum.groupby('A').sum()
np_cnt = df_dum.to_numpy()
np_mul = np.matmul(np_cnt,np_cnt.T)
```

but it takes way too much time and memory and does not run with my 1M rows. In addition, the diagonal is coumputed whereas I don't need it and I think that passing through the dummy is not so much a good idea especially because the resulting binary is really sparse.

But I don't have any more ideas...

What would you propose ?

EDIT:

for a little bit more of context, let's say that A are students and B are courses.
In the end I want to know for any two students, how much courses they have together. And that for every couple of students that at least share a course.
If that makes more sense :)

Comment: Check your code. What is `PRODUCT`?

Comment: sorry that's fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `itertools.permutations`:

```
import itertools

sets = df.groupby('B')['A'].apply(lambda x : list(itertools.permutations(x, 2))).explode().tolist()
sets = pd.DataFrame(sets)

index = df["A"].unique()
output = pd.crosstab(sets[0],sets[1],rownames=[None],colnames=[None]).reindex(index).reindex(index, axis=1)

>>> output
    a1  a2  a3  a4
a1   0   1   2   1
a2   1   0   0   0
a3   2   0   0   2
a4   1   0   2   0
```

If you want to mask the cells where index and columns are the same with "xx":

```
output = output.mask(output.index.values[:,None] == output.columns.values[None,:]).fillna("xx")

>>> output
     a1   a2   a3   a4
a1   xx  1.0  2.0  1.0
a2  1.0   xx  0.0  0.0
a3  2.0  0.0   xx  2.0
a4  1.0  0.0  2.0   xx
```

Comment: I have to confess that I don't  get it at all because I did not use those before. I'm a little bit scared by the lambda though since every time I had to use them with a big amount of data it always took a really long time to run....
But I'm gonna try it anyway and tell you if that works well.
Thanks

Comment: after analysis it seems to work fine. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use matrix multiplication of a smaller table:

```
import numpy as np

s = df.pivot_table(index = 'A', columns = 'B', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
t = s @ s.T
np.fill_diagonal(t.to_numpy(), 0)
t
A   a1  a2  a3  a4
A                 
a1   0   1   2   1
a2   1   0   0   0
a3   2   0   0   2
a4   1   0   2   0
```

Note that you can fill the diagonal with whatever you want. Or better leave it.